# Why error occurs when creating the trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, innodb, mariadb

I am trying to add a trigger through phpmyadmin 4.4

[image]

I get the error:

[image]

Why is this happening? How to declare a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with `BEGIN`, end with `END`.  Put the various statements between them.

Notice in the error how it is alread providing `FOR EACH ...`, but it is depending on you to do the rest.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html (and other pages) for the complete syntax that phpmyadmin is "helping" you generate.